# How can I stop Hibernate EventListeners?

Tags: java, hibernate, listener, event-listener

Here I am using **hibernate 4.0.1.Final**, 
For Example,

```
class MyClassListener extends DefaultPreLoadEventListener
{
 @Override
    public void onPreLoad(PreLoadEvent event) 
    {
           <!-- do something -->
    }
}
```

Hibernate `EventListener` Structure is,

1. pre       --->  after completed, 
2. run       --->  **want to stop this default listener**.  
3. post      --->  This also no need.

In my Hibernate Service class, when I call `entityManager.find(Employee.class, empId);`

Before that **MyClassListener will call**. After Completing this listener process, **I want to stop the Hibernate find method Listener**. How it is possible? any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation [at the hibernate site](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-checkconstraints.html#validator-checkconstraints-orm-hibernateevent)

I believe all you need to do is to set this property:

```
javax.persistence.validation.mode = "none"
```

Comment: javax.persistence.validation.mode  this package not there in Hibernate 4.0.1.Final. Please tell any other way to solve this problem? JoeG

Comment: It _should_ be there as that doc link was from 4.0.1.  Here is the sentence:  "To avoid validation even though Hibernate Validator is in the classpath set javax.persistence.validation.mode to none."   Am using it in 4.1.5.Final without problems....

Comment: How can I set classPath for this javax.persistence.validation.mode ? explain briefly.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand.  The value you need to set is just a property.  You can do it in code or on the command line (with a -D).  Not sure what you mean about classpath....

Comment: I tried that one also, didn't work. Is it possible to stop that defaultLoadEventListener?